# COUNTIF function comparing dates as a criteria is not working

Tags: excel-2013, countif

I am using Excel 2013. I have a worksheet that has training completion dates for our employees. I need to determine the percentage of employees that have completed the training. I am using the below COUNTIF formula, but the return is a 0 even though the majority of dates are after 1/1/2018.

=COUNTIF(J9:J444,">=1/1/2018")

I thought maybe the excel report I am exporting from our tracking system is putting the dates in an unrecognized format but the below formula works just fine:

=IF(J9>=1/1/2018,"YES","NO")

Am I using the wrong format for the COUNTIF function? I don't think I am because excel is not giving me an error, it is just returning a 0.

Thank you for your assistance!
-Curtis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the date into a Date function. Dates can be ambiguous, so to make sure it's interpreted the way you want it to, try

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A8,">="&DATE(2018,1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, unfortunately this is not working either.  After further investigation it seems that when the report is generated, the dates are being formatted as text, so both "COUNTIF" formats work fine when I manually retype the dates, which is pointless considering I will have to pull new reports monthly.  Thank you again for your assistance!

Comment: you may not need to retype anything. You could use Power Query, a free add-in from Microsoft, to transform the text back to dates and then your formula can work.